# Environment begin or end in Heading definition

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, multicol

I'm trying to include an automatic `\end{multicols}` and `\begin{multicols}{2}` before and after my Chapter headings. (The document is 2 column, the chapter headings are meant to be across the page.)

Here's my minimal working example:

This works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\thechapter}{0em}{}[]

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\end{multicols}
\chapter{Breaking Things}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

However, moving the `\begin` & `\end` into the titleformat command produces errors. It's a different error for each (as I've tried each separately). \protect doesn't help.

Minimal broken example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\thechapter}{0em}{\end{multicols}}[\begin{multicols}{2}]

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\chapter{Breaking Things}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Putting `\end{multicols}` into the "before" part of the command as shown above creates a "Missing } inserted" problem.
Putting `\begin{multicols}` into the "after" part of the command as shown above (leaving the `\end{multicols}` in the document itself) creates a "Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup." error.

Comment: Simple question: Why you do not use `twocolumn` option of your documentclass: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}`?

Comment: Because of a lot of other complicated formatting that breaks in twocolumn.

Comment: Side comment: Do you really want to have no spacing between chapter number and chapter title: i.e. `1Breaking things`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to redefine the `\chapter` command slightly, inserting the `\begin{multicols}{2}` directly after the chapter heading and `\end{multicols}`
just before the true chapter command is issued.

However, this would leave an unopened `multicol` at the beginning and an unclosed `multicol` at the end. The environment hooks `\AtBeginDocument` and `\AtEndEnvironment` open and close this environment by definition.

Comment out the `\AtBeginDocument` if you want to shift the `\begin{multicols}{2}` to a later place -- do this manually then. The same holds true for an earlier `\end{multicols}` towards the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\thechapter}{0em}{}[]



\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredchapter@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\end{multicols}\relax%
\LaTeXStandardChapter{#1}%
\begin{multicols}{2}
  % 
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredchapter@opt}{\unstarredchapter@noopt}
}%

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}%
}%


\makeatother

\AtEndDocument{%
\end{multicols}\relax%
}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\begin{multicols}{2}\relax%
}%



\begin{document}
\blindtext
\chapter{Breaking Things}
\blindtext[2]

\chapter{Other stuff}
\blindtext[4]

\end{document}
```

**Note**

My solution has the *problem* the automatic opening of a `multicols` at the beginning, since this will provide the `\tableofcontents` in two columns as well, the same is true for `\listof....` content lists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Christian, that solves the problem. Is there a simple explanation as to why I can't use the simplistic approach I used above? IE, why does it create errors?

Comment: I do not use `titlesec` at all, as it is not compatible with the KOMA bundle (preferred by me), but I assume, it's the last two arguments of your `\titleformat` command -- it seems to be something in *horizontal mode* which does not fit with the special setup of `multicols`. I am trying to provide a shorter version, without the redefinition overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a second approach that uses a feature from the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package for displaying titles across columns using an optional argument to the `mulicols` environment.

I have defined a new `\Chapter` command. Initially I just overwrote `\chapter` but then I thought it is better practise to leave the real chapter alone. My code has `\chapter` open and close the `multicols` environment, so if you want the material before the first chapter in multi-column mode then you have to do this manually.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[compact,tiny]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{\thechapter}{0em}{}[]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\endLastMultiCols\relax
\newcommand\Chapter[2][\relax]{\endLastMultiCols% end the last multicols, if there was one
  \begin{multicols}{2}[\protect{\ifx\relax#1\relax\chapter{#2}\else\chapter[#1]{#2}\fi}]%
  \def\endLastMultiCols{\end{multicols}}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\endLastMultiCols}

\begin{document}
\Chapter{Breaking Things}
\blindtext
\Chapter{Breaking more Things}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```