# Including section in an environment

Tags: sectioning, patching, answers

I am trying to adapt touhami's solution to [How to print out only statements (theorems, lemmata, etc) from a tex file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291639/how-to-print-out-only-statements-theorems-lemmata-etc-from-a-tex-file/291682?noredirect=1#comment874051_291682) so that I can also print the section titles.

My first guess would have been to use `\pretocmd{\section}{\begin{myenv}}{}{}` and `\apptocmd{\section}{\end{myenv}}{}{}`.
But accordingly to [Environment begin or end in Heading definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196417/environment-begin-or-end-in-heading-definition) it does not seem to be a good idea to patch `\section`

So I tried to adapt Christian Hupfer solution to the same question this way :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}

\newtheorem{xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{xlemma}{Lemma}


\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection}{0em}{}[]

\newif\ifonly % uncomment next line
\onlytrue   
\ifonly
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{lemma}{mtlemma}{mtfile}
\Newassociation{theorem}{mttheorem}{mtfile}
\Newassociation{sectionenv}{mtsectionenv}{mtfile}
\renewenvironment{mttheorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\renewenvironment{mtlemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\renewenvironment{mtsectionenv}{}{}

\let\LaTeXStandardSection\section
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unstarredsection@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredsection@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection@opt}[2][]{%
\begin{sectionenv}\relax%
\LaTeXStandardSection{#1}%
\end{sectionenv}
  % 
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredsection}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredsection@opt}{\unstarredsection@noopt}
}%

\newcommand{\starredsection}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*{#1}
}%

\renewcommand{\section}{%
\@ifstar{\starredsection}{\unstarredsection}%
}%


\makeatother

\Opensolutionfile{mtfile}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\AtEndDocument{%
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\handlethispage\relax
\Closesolutionfile{mtfile}
\Readsolutionfile{mtfile}}
\else
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\newenvironment{lemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}

\fi


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lemma}
this is some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}

\section{First section}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{theorem}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{lemma}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

However, it still does not work. The mtfile.tex contains the following lines, in which the blank spaces are probably (part of ?) the problem :

```
\begin{mtsectionenv}{}
\LaTeXStandardSection {First section}\end {sectionenv}
```

Any idea of what is wrong ?

Comment: It does not work with patching the section because `titlesec` changes the section command.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I included titlesec in my example because I will need it later and that I thought it could be the reason of some problems...
However : if I remove titlesec, the problem is still here.

Comment: I'll take a look later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. For (sub)sections like commands one needs

```
\pretocmd\@startsection{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\csname\space #1\string\endcsname}}{}{} 
\pretocmd\@sect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{[#7]{#8}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@ssect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{*{#5}}}{}{}
```

for parts

```
\pretocmd\@part{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@spart{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part*{#1}}}{}{}
```

and for chapters

```
\pretocmd\@chapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@schapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter*{#1}}}{}{}
```

We also need to disable counters by adding

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\mtrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\refstepcounter\@gobble
```

and

```
\AtEndDocument{%
\let\refstepcounter\mtrefstepcounter
```

If  table of contents (toc) is used one need to type

```
\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\tableofcontents}
```

**Example**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}

\newtheorem{xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{xlemma}{Lemma}

\newif\ifonly % uncomment next line
%\onlytrue 

\makeatletter  
\ifonly
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{lemma}{mtlemma}{mtfile}
\Newassociation{theorem}{mttheorem}{mtfile}
\renewenvironment{mttheorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\renewenvironment{mtlemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\Opensolutionfile{mtfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\@startsection{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\csname\space #1\string\endcsname}}{}{} 
\pretocmd\@sect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{[#7]{#8}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@ssect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{*{#5}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@part{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@spart{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part*{#1}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@chapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@schapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter*{#1}}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\mtrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\refstepcounter\@gobble
\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\AtEndDocument{%
\let\refstepcounter\mtrefstepcounter
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\handlethispage\relax
\Closesolutionfile{mtfile}
\Readsolutionfile{mtfile}}
\else
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\newenvironment{lemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\ifonly\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\tableofcontents}\else\tableofcontents\fi
\section{Foo}
\section{Foo bar}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
this is some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{theorem}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** for use with `titlesec`

First we need to replace

```
\pretocmd\@startsection{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\csname\space #1\string\endcsname}}{}{} 
\pretocmd\@sect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{[#7]{#8}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@ssect{\Writetofile{mtfile}{*{#5}}}{}{}
```

with

```
\pretocmd\ttl@straight@i{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\csname\space#1\string\endcsname\ifttl@label [#2]\else*\fi{#3}}}{}{}
```

if commands `\part` and `\chapter` are changed too we need to do some changes
with

`\ttl@part@i` for part in article class

`\ttl@top@i` for chapter and `\ttl@page@i` for part in book class.

and we need to replace

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\mtrefstepcounter\refstepcounter
\let\refstepcounter\@gobble
```

with

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\mtstepcounter\stepcounter
\let\stepcounter\@gobble
\let\Currentlabel\empty
```

and

```
\AtEndDocument{%
\let\refstepcounter\mtrefstepcounter
```

with

```
\AtEndDocument{%
\let\stepcounter\mtstepcounter
```

**Example**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{}{\thesection}{0em}{}[]

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\newcommand{\handlethispage}{}
\AtBeginShipout{\handlethispage}

\newtheorem{xtheorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{xlemma}{Lemma}

\newif\ifonly % uncomment next line
\onlytrue  
\makeatletter 
\ifonly
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{lemma}{mtlemma}{mtfile}
\Newassociation{theorem}{mttheorem}{mtfile}
\renewenvironment{mttheorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\renewenvironment{mtlemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\Opensolutionfile{mtfile}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\@part{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@spart{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\part*{#1}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@chapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter[#1]{#2}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\@schapter{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\chapter*{#1}}}{}{}
\pretocmd\ttl@straight@i{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\csname\space#1\string\endcsname\ifttl@label [#2]\else*\fi{#3}}}{}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\mtstepcounter\stepcounter
\let\stepcounter\@gobble
\let\Currentlabel\empty
\let\handlethispage\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}
\AtEndDocument{%
\let\stepcounter\mtstepcounter
\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}
\let\handlethispage\relax
\Closesolutionfile{mtfile}
\Readsolutionfile{mtfile}}
\else
\newenvironment{theorem}{\begin{xtheorem}}{\end{xtheorem}}
\newenvironment{lemma}{\begin{xlemma}}{\end{xlemma}}
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\ifonly\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\tableofcontents}\else\tableofcontents\fi
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
this is some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{theorem}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{lemma}
some bla bla in lamma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! You forgot `\usepackage{answers}` in your example.

Comment: However, this solution does not work if using titlesec.

Comment: i'll try to see what happen with `titlesec`.

Comment: I understand that many things are changing with titlesec, but I don't understand what. If anyone has a reference about this (the documentation of titlesec does not seem to help), it would be very helpful.

Comment: Suggestions on what to do if there is an `\appendix` command in the file?  The section numbering is then A, B, C, instead of 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @Joel you can add `\let\mtappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\Writetofile{mtfile}{\string\appendix}}` to `\AtBeginDocument` and `\let\appendix\mtappendix` to `\AtEndDocument`.